# How to save multiple dataframe using one variable in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, analysis

```
import numpy as np

count = np.arange(0,1849)
for i in range(0,6):   
  for j in range (0,6):
    for k in range (0,4):
        for l in range (0,10):
            for m in count:
              case = data[(data["CURRENT_ENERGY_RATING_Code"] == i)&(data["PROPERTY_TYPE"] == j)&(data["BUILT_FORM"] == k)&(data["CONSTRUCTION_AGE_BAND"] == l)]
              case[m] = pd.DataFrame()
```

I wanted to save multiple data frames within the case variable with a proper number like case1, case2, etc.
So I can view each data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Guys,

```
number = 1
for i in range(0,7):
  for k in range(0,4):
    for m in range(0,6):
      for n in range(0,11):
        case = data[(data["CURRENT_ENERGY_RATING_Code"] == i)&(data["PROPERTY_TYPE_Code"] == k)&(data["BUILT_FORM_Code"] == m)&(data["CONSTRUCTION_AGE_BAND_Code"] == n)]
        case.to_csv(f"simul\All_Parameters\simul_{number}.csv")
        number += 1
```

This Code work's for me, I saved the output in a local folder

Answer (score 0):

Created names conflict with variables already used by your logic, so you need to use all variables `(i, j, k, l, m)` or a counter like this:

```
d = {}
number = 1

d['case' + str(number)] = pd.DataFrame()
number += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary with keys in the format `i-j-k-l-m` iterating through 0,1,2,etc; and values as the relevant dataframes. For example:

```
dic = {}
count = np.arange(0,1849)
for i in range(0,6):   
    for j in range (0,6):
        for k in range (0,4):
            for l in range (0,10):
                for m in count:
                    key = str(i) + '-' + str(j) + '-' + str(k) + '-' + str(l) + '-' + str(m)
                    dic[key] = data[(data["CURRENT_ENERGY_RATING_Code"] == i)&(data["PROPERTY_TYPE"] == j)&(data["BUILT_FORM"] == k)&(data["CONSTRUCTION_AGE_BAND"] == l)]
print(dic)
#note resulting `dic` is a huge dictionary!
```